# Is There Such A Thing As "Multi-Path Push" in Firebase Real-Time Datasbase?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2, nosql

I was watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i1n9Kw3AORw&index=7&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s) which talks about *multi-path updates* in Firebase. Multi-path updates are great because they allow you to call the firebaseRef.update() method two or more times while having them be one atomic, all-or-nothing operation.

This is great, but in my current situation I don't want to use the *update()* method. Instead, I want to use the FirebaseRef's *push* method and allow Firebase to generate a unique key for my object.

The tricky part is that I have denormalized my data so that it's in two places. What I would really like to do is have an atomic, all-or-nothing operation that uses Firebase's *push()* operation to create a unique key and then save the object with that key in 2 or more different places inside of my database data. However, the syntax for push() already uses an object so is what I want to do even possible?

*Note: Another possible solution may be to use Firebase api to somehow generate a unique key in the client and then do a standard multipath update using that generated key as the key for my object being inserted.*

Comment: You note at the end is the answer to your question.

var key = firebase.database().ref('somestring').push();

will return you a key without writing anything in firebase database. Use that key to make your object and then call update()

Comment: But suppose a user leaves the app after the first goes through and before the second goes through. Then my denormalized data is in an inconsistent state. I want to do it all in one atomic operation.

Comment: then use transaction() it is built for that purpose. But as my personal viewpoint only use transactions if it is really necessary.

Comment: transaction will not work in this situation. If you believe it does please post an answer.

Answer (score 13):

There is no multi-location push, but because push IDs are generated on the client, you can use a multi-location update to do what you want.

You can generate a push ID by calling `push` with no arguments. Push IDs are generated on the client and generating one involves no interaction with the database:

```ts
let key = firebase.database().ref().push().key;
```

You can use AngularFire2 to do this, too; although, you have to pass an argument (`undefined`) to `push` to appease TypeScript:

```ts
let key = angularFire.database.list('').push(undefined).key;
```

Once you've generated the key, you can create a multi-location update:

```ts
let obj = { some: 'object' };
angularFire.database.object('').update({
    [`a/path/${key}`]: obj,
    [`another/path${key}`]: obj
});
```

The update is atomic, so either all of the paths will be updated or none will.

Comment: awesome. Using push with no arguments was the key! (no pun intended hehe)