# Is there a way in AngularFire firebase to get multipath data in one query

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I want to get data snapshot or valueChanges() from these two paths `diretory/0GZfwgQqXRcJ3o2G23vClsEbPay1/files` and `directory/BgHYpuDpE3c7tRYuG2d8k0xHr2E2/files`.
However these paths will be dynamic and can be more than one. I dont want to apply for loop and subscribe to each path. I want single collection array with all these snapshots.
How to do this using AngularFire Library?

Database Structure here

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can`t. Firebase does not support multi path queries. You can use the help of rsjx to join two observables and wait for their result to return and then join them. see this article for more info [Is There Such A Thing As "Multi-Path Push" in Firebase Real-Time Datasbase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41490132/is-there-such-a-thing-as-multi-path-push-in-firebase-real-time-datasbase)

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Realtime Database always retrieves full nodes. While it **is** possible to filter what child nodes are returned with a query, there is no way to return a subset of the properties of each child nodes.

When you need this, it typically means that you should restructure your data to allow the use-case. For example in your JSON, you could have a top-level `files` child, which then the directory ID under it, and *just the* files for that directly. That way you could read all the files by reading `/files`.

The Firebase documentation covers this under [avoid nesting data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data#avoid_nesting_data) and [flattening your data structures](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data#avoid_nesting_data).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43484811/firebase-multipath-fetch-data you are not getting my point. I want something like this in AngularFire.. call more than one path having no parent child relation. they can be in different parents as well.but to combine two paths and get their snapshots in one query

Comment: You can't do it in one query. My answer to the question you link fires two queries. You can do the same in AngularFire and join the two streams/observables. For an example of that, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46529904/angular-firebase-merge-two-observables-into-one

Comment: thanks Frank. any good resource from where I can learn queries and joins of firebase

Comment: I did a search for "angular fire merge observables" to find the above, so that'd be a good place to start I guess.